# Encode specific characters within tag attributes

Tags: php, regex

Using PHP, I would like to encode specific characters (the `>` and `<` characters) within the attribute values for *any* tag.

For example, `<input type="text" data-name="Oliver<>Nassar">` would become `<input type="text" data-name="Oliver&lt;&gt;Nassar">`.

I'm not picky regarding the attribute name (eg. `data-name` or `value` attribute names). While I am happy to presume a whitespace character (`\s`) before the attribute value (eg. `<input data-name="...">`) it would be great if that were not a condition, such that I could meet cases such as `<input type="text"data-name="Oliver<>Nassar">`

I imagine PHPs `preg_replace_callback` will be made use of, but as far the actual expression, I could use some help there.

Comment: Any particular reason why you've added regex tag?

Comment: I believe I'll need a regular expression to match the contents of the attribute values.

Comment: Check out [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags) and see if you still want regex for that...

Comment: Have you considered [`htmlentites`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) or [`htmlspecialchars`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php)?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Thanks. I've stumbled into that many times. I understand the intention behind it, but maintain this listed question.

Comment: @Passerby I will use those if I am able to match the case using regex

Answer (score 0):

Here is the expression I came up with:

```
'/' .
    '(' .
        '\s{1}' .
        '[a-z\-]+' .
        '\s?' .
        '=' .
        '\s?' .
        '(' .
            '[\'|"]{1}' .
        ')' .
    ')' .
    '([^\2]*)' .
    '\2' .
'/iU',
```

Hope this is helpful to someone else.